# Integration by change the variable

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification, indefinite-integrals

> Let, $\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1+e^x}\operatorname{dx}$. Write as an integral of a rational function and compute it.
>
> **Suggest**: change the variable in order to eliminate the square root.

My work was:

Let $u^2=1+e^x$, so $u=\sqrt{1+e^x}$. One also have $e^x=u^2-1$.

Then one got $\operatorname{du}=\frac{e^x}{2\sqrt{1+e^x}}\operatorname{dx}$ and so $\operatorname{dx}=\frac{2\sqrt{1+e^x}}{e^x}\operatorname{du}$.

Now substituting:

$$\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1+e^x}\operatorname{dx}=\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{u^2}\frac{2\sqrt{1+e^x}}{e^x}\operatorname{du}=\int_{-1}^1u\frac{2\sqrt{u^2}}{u^2-1}\operatorname{du}=$$

$$=2\int_{-1}^1\frac{u^2}{u^2-1}\operatorname{du}=2\int_{-1}^11+\frac{1}{u^2-1}\operatorname{du}=$$
$$=2\int_{-1}^11 \operatorname{du}+2\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{u^2-1}\operatorname{du}$$

Is this thought right?

And what is the second integral? Is not the $\arctan$! Thanks

Comment: You forgot to change the limit of integration.

Comment: You're forgetting to adjust the limits of integration when you make the substitution.

Comment: The pieces all seem to be there. Since you changed the variable, don't forget to make the corresponding change of limits of integration. For the last integral, factor the denominator and rewrite it using partial fractions.

Comment: Since $u=\sqrt{1+e^x}$ then the lower bound would be $\sqrt{1+e^{-1}}$ and the upper bound would be $\sqrt{1+e}$. Thanks

Comment: Use partial fractions on the second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing your work, we will obtain
\begin{align}
\int\sqrt{1+e^x}\ dx&=2\int\ du+2\int\frac1{u^2-1}\ du\\
&=2u+\int\left[\frac1{u-1}-\frac1{u+1}\right]\ du\\
&=2u+\ln|u-1|-\ln|u+1|+C\\
&=2u+\ln\left|\frac{u-1}{u+1}\right|+C\\
&=2\sqrt{1+e^x}+\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{1+e^x}-1}{\sqrt{1+e^x}+1}\right|+C.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to do the second integral is to use the fact that $\frac{1}{u^2 - 1} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{u-1} - \frac{1}{u+1})$

Comment: Just be careful if your limits are beyond $-1$, $1$

Answer (score 3):

You've done just fine thus far. For the second integral, if you don't want to use partial fraction decomposition, which is likely the easiest route, then the correct trigonometric substitution would be $$u = \sec \theta\implies du = \sec\theta\tan\theta \,d\theta$$